# How to reference functions in another indicator from your indicator script?

Tags: function, pine-script

I'm only wanting to call a function in an indicator from my indicator script. 
For example:
How would I call the DI+ function in the DMI Oscillator indicator from my indicator?

Specifically trying to add these 3 together for an IF statement:

if SMA 20 Crosses SMA 50 on BTCUSD
and 
Weis Wave Volume Moves Up 1.0% in 2 bars 
and
BTC Average Volume Crosses above BTC Average Volume 
then
strategy.entry
else
strategy.noentry

Comment: Is the indicator called exactly "DMI Oscillator"? I couldn't find it.

Comment: _BTC Average Volume Crosses above BTC Average Volume_ - how can this happen ?